# Get the first line for each ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Today, I would like to get the list of all events of a list which have been selected or have the farest date. I actually use the following code

```
SELECT choices.id AS id, events.id AS event_id,
events.owner_id, choices.selected, 
choices_dates.label AS events_date
FROM events
LEFT JOIN polls ON (events.id = polls.event_id)
LEFT JOIN choices ON (polls.id = choices.poll_id)
LEFT JOIN choices_dates ON (choices.id = choices_dates.choice_id)
WHERE polls.kind = 'date'
ORDER BY events.id, choices.selected DESC, events_date DESC;
```

I obtain this result :

```
id         event_id         owner_id         selected         events_date
2          1         1         0         2011-04-20 12:00:00
1          1         1         0         2011-04-20 00:00:00
7          2         1         0         2011-04-20 12:00:00
6          2         1         0         2011-04-20 00:00:00
13         3         1         0         2011-04-22 15:57:54
12         3         1         0         2011-04-20 12:00:00
11         3         1         0         2011-04-20 00:00:00
```

But here is what I want :

```
id         event_id         owner_id         selected         events_date
2          1         1         0         2011-04-20 12:00:00
7          2         1         0         2011-04-20 12:00:00
13         3         1         0         2011-04-22 15:57:54
```

I can't do nested query because I am creating a VIEW and the group by gives me random results (I obtain the first line for the event_id 1, and the last one for the event_id 2, ...)

For now, I could do the job with php function, but it is not optimisez and my code is dirty.

Does someone have any idea for doing this with a great SQL function ?

Thanks,
Kevin

EDIT : I've successeed to do what i want : I've used two different VIEW :

CREATE VIEWview_events_maxAS
SELECT
events.id AS event_id,
MAX(choices.selected) AS max_selected,
MAX(choices_dates.label) AS max_events_date
FROM events
LEFT JOIN polls ON (events.id = polls.event_id)
LEFT JOIN choices ON (polls.id = choices.poll_id)
LEFT JOIN choices_dates ON (choices.id = choices_dates.choice_id)
WHERE polls.kind = 'date'
GROUP BY event_id

AND

CREATE VIEW view_events_correct AS (
SELECT
choices.id AS id,
events.id AS event_id,
events.owner_id,
choices.selected,
choices_dates.label AS event_date
FROM events
LEFT JOIN polls ON (events.id = polls.event_id)
LEFT JOIN choices ON (polls.id = choices.poll_id)
LEFT JOIN choices_dates ON (choices.id = choices_dates.choice_id
INNER JOIN view_events_max ON (events.id = view_events_max.event_id AND (choices.selected = 1 OR (choices.selected = view_events_max.max_selected AND choices_dates.label = view_events_max.max_events_date)))
)

Thanks everybody for your help, Kevin

Comment: Does your flavor of SQL support the `HAVING` clause in combination with the `GROUP BY` clause?  Something like `HAVING MAX(events_date)=events_date` in combination with a `GROUP BY event_id`.  Alternatively, use a sub-query.

Comment: How do you define `FIRST`, since it looks like it's not dependent on the `id` or the `events_date`?

Comment: MySQL support the HAVING clause, but for example, when I execute this code :
`...GROUP BY event_id
HAVING choices.selected = MAX(choices.selected)`
and if one result is selected (selected=1), I've got only two results :
`6  2  1  0  2011-04-20 00:00:00  
11  3  1  0  2011-04-20 00:00:00`

`FIRST` is the first element I found when I order my results by selected and then by events_date.

Answer (score 1):

I know in Oracle you could use analytic functions to do this.  I dont know if there is something similar for mySql...

```
select id, event_id, owner_id, selected, events_date from (
SELECT choices.id AS id, events.id AS event_id, events.owner_id as owner_id,
choices.selected as selected,
choices_dates.label AS events_date,
max(choices_date.label) over (partition by events.id) as max_events_date
FROM events LEFT JOIN polls ON (events.id = polls.event_id) LEFT JOIN choices ON
(polls.id = choices.poll_id) LEFT JOIN choices_dates ON (choices.id =
choices_dates.choice_id)
WHERE polls.kind = 'date') innerview
where events_date = max_events_date
order by event_id, selected DESC, events_date DESC;
```

Comment: By the way, I can't do nested query (`SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...)`).

Comment: In this case however this does not effect performance.  The outer query does no additional database read/writes than were done in the inner query, the purpose of the outer query here is to select just the columns that you want to return and to remove the rows that are not the MAX_EVENT_DATE.  This is the best performing query possible for your situation, run an explain plan on it and prove me wrong.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to, it's that I can't. It seems that these kind of queries don't work on `VIEW` in MySQL...

Comment: @Kevin: What makes you say that? What errors do you get? Did you read through the documentation?

Comment: @Kevin: You're right: [The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this (untested, lacking both a description of the schema, and the version of your database software) work?

```
select choices.id as id
     , events.id as event_id
     , events.owner_id
     , choices.selected
     , choices_dates.label as events_date
from
(
    SELECT events.id as max_event_id
         , max(choices_dates.label) as max_events_date
    FROM events
    LEFT JOIN polls ON (events.id = polls.event_id)
    LEFT JOIN choices ON (polls.id = choices.poll_id)
    LEFT JOIN choices_dates ON (choices.id = choices_dates.choice_id)
    WHERE polls.kind = 'date'
    GROUP BY events.id
) 
LEFT JOIN polls ON (events.id = polls.event_id)
LEFT JOIN choices ON (polls.id = choices.poll_id)
LEFT JOIN choices_dates ON (choices.id = choices_dates.choice_id)
where events_date = max_events_date
  and events.id = max_event_id
```

Comment: That should work but it would perform poorly compared to using analytics.  I am not sure if analytic functions exist in MySQL, but it is situations like this that remind me why Oracle is worth the money.